# How to truncate a string wrapped in a bounding rect in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have a simple `QGraphicsView` with text written over it. That text is wrapped under a `bounding rect`.  I want to `truncate` the leading characters of text according to width of the bounding rect.
If my string is `"I am loving Qt"` and if my bounding rect is allowing `7 chars` then it should show like `...g Qt`. Text should not be written in multiple lines. According to width, more chars can be fit.
Along with I am interested to know, how the text can be aligned ?

widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    view->setScene(scene);
}  
void Widget::on_textButton_clicked()
{
    Text* t = new Text() ;
    QString s = "I am loving Qt";
    QGraphicsTextItem* text = t->drawText(s);
    scene->addItem(text);
}
```

Text.h

```
class Text : public QGraphicsTextItem
{

public:
    explicit Text(const QString &text);
    Text();
    QGraphicsTextItem* drawText(QString s);
    virtual void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

 }
```

Text.cpp

```
QGraphicsTextItem* Text::drawText(QString s)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem *t = new Text(s);
    t->setTextWidth(8);
    return t;
}     
     
void Text::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(230,230,230));
    painter->drawRect(option->rect);
    QGraphicsTextItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
}
```

Comment: What is a `Text`? What is base class?

Comment: @MarekR I have updated the code. Please, look in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [QFontMetrics::elidedText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText) by giving the font, width of your `Text` object and the actual text, and it will return the ***elided*** text. There are also a few [Qt::TextElideMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextElideMode-enum) options to choose from.

Comment: Can you look into this question ?  My paint() is not working properly while `zoom-in` when I used  `QFontMetrics::elidedText`.  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840233/paint-is-not-working-while-using-qfontmetricselidedtext-in-qt