# How to use QPainter::setTransform in paint() in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have a simple `QGraphicsView` with text written over it.That text is wrapped under a bounding rect. I have truncated a text using  `QFontMetrics::elidedText`.
When initially view gets loaded, it shows all truncated text properly. But when I `zoom-in` only few truncated text gets visible. If for few more times I `zoomed-in`, then some times it shows all the truncated text and some times , it never shows any truncated text.
Before truncated text code gets added, `zoom-in` was working properly.

widget.cpp

```
  void widget::ZoomIn()
  {
      double scaleFactor = 1.1;
      view->scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
  }
void Widget::on_textButton_clicked()
{
    //logic to get string s and its co-ordinates firstPos and secondPos
    Text* t = new Text() ;
    QGraphicsTextItem* text = t->drawText(s,firstPos,secondPos,50,40);
    scene->addItem(text);
}
```

Text.cpp

```
Text::Text(const QString &text,int left,int top,int width,int height)
    : QGraphicsTextItem (text),currentString(text),
    Left(left),Top(top),Width(width),Height(height)
{}     

Text::Text(){}

QGraphicsTextItem  *Text::drawText(QString s, int left,int top,int width,int height)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem  *text = new Text(s,left,top,width,height);
    return text;
}     

void Text::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    QFont defaultFont = QApplication::font();
    QFontMetrics fm = QFontMetrics(defaultFont);
    QRect rect = QRect(Left,Top,Width,Height);
    QString elidedText = fm.elidedText(currentString, Qt::ElideLeft,rect.width());
    
    QTransform trans = view->transform();
    QTransform prevTrans;
    painter->setTransform(trans);
    painter->drawText(rect,Qt::AlignRight,elidedText);
    painter->setTransform(prevTrans);
    
}
```

I understood that,  in `zoom-in` I am changing transformation and painter is drawing on old transformation. So I have to take transformation from `view` and set it with `painter` then `drawText()` and then set `painter` transformation as previous transformation.
I did , but still problem persist.

Comment: As long as you are implementing your own painting using ```QPainter::drawText``` it is fine to inherit from ```QGraphicsItem```. There is not point to derive from ```QGraphicsTextItem```

Comment: @SoheilArmin  I was just told that, in `zoom-in` I am changing `transformation`  and `painter` is drawing on old `transformation`. So I have to take `transformation` from `view` and reset it with `painter`. Something like that. may be I can not explain it properly. I tried to do it but problem is still there. And I have updated `painter` code. Please look in to it.

Comment: I don't get the point to get transform form the view and apply it to the painter! Probably you don't need to do that.